# Stretch the values of a pytorch tensor

Tags: pytorch

I wish to 'stretch' the last two dimensions of a pytorch tensor to increase the spatial resolution of a (batch, channels, y, x) tensor.

Minimal example (I need 'new_function')

```py
a = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = new_function(a, (2, 3))
print(b)
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
        [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]])
```

One way of doing this (for the real problem):

```py
a = torch.ones((2, 256, 2, 2)) # my original data.
b = torch.zeros((2, 256, 80, 96)) # The output I need
b[:, :, :40, :48] = a[:, :, 0, 0]
b[:, :, 40:, :48] = a[:, :, 1, 0]
b[:, :, :40, 48:] = a[:, :, 0, 1]
b[:, :, 40:, 48:] = a[:, :, 1, 1]
```

Comment: why not use nearest neighbor interpretation?

Comment: Would that preserve the gradients?

Comment: sure. look at nn.upsample: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/upsampling.html#Upsample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `torch.nn.functional.interpolate` (thanks to Shai)

```py
torch.nn.functional.interpolate(input_tensor.float(), size=(4, 6))
```

My original idea was to use a variety of `view` and `repeat` methods:

```py
def stretch(e, sdims):
    od = e.shape
    return e.view(od[0], od[1], -1, 1).repeat(1, 1, 1, sdims[-1]).view(od[0], od[1], od[2], -1).repeat(1, 1, 1, sdims[-2]).view(od[0], od[1], od[2] * sdims[0], od[3] * sdims[1])
```

```py
torch.Size([2, 2, 4, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `torch.kron()` with `torch.ones(2,3)`.

```
a = torch.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = torch.kron(a,torch.ones(2,3))
print(b)
```

returns

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.],
        [3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4.],
        [3., 3., 3., 4., 4., 4.]])
```

Comment: Although this is an interesting solution to explore, the only problem I have is that it only works for expanding beyond the current dimensionality. @jmsinusa's answer allows to stretch or shrink using the interpolate function, which also has the added feature of being able to chose whioch algorithm to use.