# Constrain elements in a PyTorch tensor to be equal

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a PyTorch tensor and would like to **impose equality constraints on its elements while optimizing**. An example tensor of 2 * 9 is shown below, where the same color indicates the elements should always be equal.

[image: Example tensor]

Let's make a minimal example of 1 * 4, and initialize the first two and last two elements to be equal respectively.

```py
import torch
x1 = torch.tensor([1.2, 1.2, -0.3, -0.3], requires_grad=True)
print(x1)
# tensor([ 1.2000,  1.2000, -0.3000, -0.3000])
```

If I perform a simple least squares directly, the equality definitely exists no more.

```py
y = torch.arange(4)
opt_1 = torch.optim.SGD([x1], lr=0.1)
opt_1.zero_grad()
loss = (y - x1).pow(2).sum()
loss.backward()
opt_1.step()
print(x1)
# tensor([0.9600, 1.1600, 0.1600, 0.3600], requires_grad=True)
```

---

I tried to express this tensor as **a weighted sum of masks**.

```py
def weighted_sum(c, masks):
    return torch.sum(torch.stack([c[0] * masks[0], c[1] * masks[1]]), axis=0)

c = torch.tensor([1.2, -0.3], requires_grad=True)
masks = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1]])
x2 = weighted_sum(c, masks)
print(x2)
# tensor([ 1.2000,  1.2000, -0.3000, -0.3000])
```

In this way, the equality remains after optimization.

```py
opt_c = torch.optim.SGD([c], lr=0.1)
opt_c.zero_grad()
y = torch.arange(4)
x2 = weighted_sum(c, masks)
loss = (y - x2).pow(2).sum()
loss.backward()
opt_c.step()
print(c)
# tensor([0.9200, 0.8200], requires_grad=True)
print(weighted_sum(c, masks))
# tensor([0.9200, 0.9200, 0.8200, 0.8200], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
```

However, the biggest issue of this solution is that I have to maintain **a large set of masks** when the input dimension is high; surely it will result in **out of memory**. Suppose the shape of input tensor is `d_0 * d_1 * ... * d_m`, and the number of equality blocks is `k`, then there will be a huge mask of shape `k * d_0 * d_1 * ... * d_m`, which is unacceptable.

---

Another solution might be **upsampling** the low resolution tensor like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55734651/stretch-the-values-of-a-pytorch-tensor). However, it cannot be applied to irregular equality blocks, e.g.,

```
tensor([[ 1.2000,  1.2000,  1.2000, -3.1000, -3.1000],
        [-0.1000,  2.0000,  2.0000,  2.0000,  2.0000]])
```

So... is there a smarter way of implementing such equality constraints in a PyTorch tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want them to always be equal, why not just remove both the first and last value from `x` and `y`? The extra values can be derived from the model output when needed after training, since they're expected to be equal to their neighbors anyway. There's no need to learn two copies of the same values.

If you want a more approximate learning that they're the same, you could add `some_weight * (torch.abs(x[0]-x[1]) + torch.abs(x[-1] - x[-2]))` to your loss function. Then your loss would be trying to learn that these are expected to be the same.

Or, instead of masks, if you have counts for each value, maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
def convert(tensor, counts):
     return torch.cat( [v.repeat(count) for (v, count) in zip(tensor, counts) ] )

convert( torch.arange(4), [3,2,1,3])
tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

Comment: Sorry that my first example might be misleading. I've shown a more general example at the beginning. The tensor dimensionality can be more than 1, and the equality can not only happen at the first two of last two elements, but also in the middle. Therefore removing the first and last value only doesn't help.

Comment: I still don't understand why your model output can't exclude duplicates and have y match the expected output. Also in your updated example, `y=torch.arange(4)`, the "correct" values you're trying to learn don't match what you want your model to learn.

Comment: The example `y=torch.arange(4)` is only for demonstration. In practice, I expect this tensor with equality constraint to learn the underlying "trend" in the data. For example, it can be used together with other free tensors to form an additive model.

Comment: I think my initial answer still holds? either the constraint is firm and you should remove (any/all) duplicate information from both inputs and outputs... or it can be learned/approximated, and so you should include the difference in your loss function?

Comment: I do agree that duplicates should be removed, but the problem is how. It's not straightforward to efficiently remove them and restore afterwards when the tensor is large and the equality pattern is irregular. As shown in my problem description, I have tried two ways for duplicates removal, either being memory consuming or limited in usability.

Comment: I added another suggestion to the answer, instead of masks. I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

On top of @nairbv's solution of repeating, I've also come up with another way to reduce the memory consumption of masking (i.e., the first tentative solution stated in my question).

The basic idea is using `reduce` to avoid unnecessary temporary tensors created during `torch.stack`.

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def weighted_sum_v2(c, masks):
    stacksum = lambda s, cm: torch.sum(torch.stack([s, cm]), dim=0)
    return reduce(stacksum, map(mul, c, masks))
```

The results are also as expected.

```py
c = torch.tensor([1.2, -0.3], requires_grad=True)
masks = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1]])
x2 = weighted_sum_v2(c, masks)
print(x2)
# tensor([ 1.2000,  1.2000, -0.3000, -0.3000])

opt_c = torch.optim.SGD([c], lr=0.1)
opt_c.zero_grad()
y = torch.arange(4)
x2 = weighted_sum_v2(c, masks)
loss = (y - x2).pow(2).sum()
loss.backward()
opt_c.step()
print(c)
# tensor([0.9200, 0.8200], requires_grad=True)
print(weighted_sum_v2(c, masks))
# tensor([0.9200, 0.9200, 0.8200, 0.8200], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a good solution to solve those constraints. The core part is use `v = torch.tensor(freedom number variables, requires_grad=True)`, then use `torch.cat()` to compose the final matrix `M`.

For example, `v = torch.rand(1, 2, requires_grad=True),  M = torch.cat([v, v], dim=0)`, then you can continue compute others
if exists other constraints, such as `sum(^2)=1`. Also use trick `v=v/torch.norm(v, p=2)`

The key is give "freedom" variables, then add some tricks to "compute" , the whole process is gradient exist